# Create a new vector every loop iteration in R

Tags: r

I have the following problem: 
I have a for-loop => `for (i in 1:20){t <- c(t,print(i:20))} ...`

I know how to save all the results in one vector, but I want to save the results of EACH iteration as an own vector (like you see it above) => so that e.g. `t[18]` is just 18 19 20 and `t[20]` is just 20
I thought about a matrix as well, but each row must end with "20" so the rest needs to be filled up with  "0" in a 20x20 matrix ...

Comment: Does this really need to be vectors? Could it be a list? More context would help.

Answer (score 1):

How about a list for that purpose:

```
lst <- list()

for (i in 1:20){
  lst[[i]] <- i:20
}
```

Then acces it by calling e.g.

```
lst[[18]]
#[1] 18 19 20
```

Answer (score 1):

I would adjust @beginneR's answer like this:

```
lst <-vector("list",20)
for (i in 1:20){
  lst[[i]] <- i:20
}
```

It is only a small addition but if makes a big difference in performance terms if you increase the size of the list (e.g millions).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly agree with @beginneR, however if you really want new variables in the loop you can use assign().

```
for (i in 1:20){
  assign(paste("t",i, sep = ""), i:20)
}
```

This will give you the variable t1, t2 etc. as you want them. Again I strongly advise to use a list this kind of approach is hardly scalable.